# Can I paint polyethylene shade fabric for outdoor use?

Tags: painting, paint

I have a sprayer and am wondering if I can spray this fabric that I'm looking to install as a privacy panel between me and my neighbors. Once it is installed it will be permanently in place. I'm never going to roll it up and down like a roller shade. It will be stapled in place and attached with pan screws and stabilized.

This is the fabric I bought just to be clear:

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0778TYDCM/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0778TYDCM)

I have it in the beige color and want to do an off-white or very pale gray to match the house better.

Can I get some recommendations for the best type of paint to use? I live in the desert and in the summer it can get up to 120°F now and then. Would the paint just peel off over time due to the extreme heat?

I know we're not allowed to promote certain brands but any sound advice would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Paint seems like asking for trouble in this application. It might last. Then again, it might not, and then you have a mess on your hands, and one that's "permanently in place" which *sounds like* daring the paint gods to smite you.